# Multiplicar caracteres de cadena con array de integer API STREAM

Tags: java-17

Buen dia, quisiera usar api stream y poder refactorizar este fragmento de codigo

```html
 String retorno = "TG40356157BR".substring(2, 10);
        String dv;
        final Integer[] multiplicadores = {8, 6, 4, 2, 3, 5, 9, 7};
        Integer soma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
          soma += new Integer(retorno.substring(i, (i + 1))) * multiplicadores[i];
        }
        System.out.println(soma);
        final Integer resto = soma % 11;
        if (resto == 0) {
          dv = "5";
        } else if (resto == 1) {
          dv = "0";
        } else {
          dv = new Integer(11 - resto).toString();
        }
        retorno += dv;
        retorno = "TG40356157BR".substring(0, 2) + retorno + "TG40356157BR".substring(10).trim();
        return retorno;
```

Por el momento he avanzado por esta parte podrian apoyarme gracias.

```html
IntStream.range(NumberUtils.INTEGER_ZERO, StringUtils.length("TG40356157BR"))
        .mapToObj(i -> StringUtils.substring(zipcode, i, (i + NumberUtils.INTEGER_ONE))).map(NumberUtils::toInt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el programa se trata de la validación del número de registro de contribuyente de impuestos brasileño.

```
    String trn = "TG40356157BR";
    String trnAValidar = trn.substring(2, 10);

    int[] multiplicadores = {8, 6, 4, 2, 3, 5, 9, 7};

    int resto = IntStream.range(0, 8)
            .map(i -> Integer.parseInt(trnAValidar.substring(i, i + 1))* multiplicadores[i])
            .sum() % 11;
    String digitoVerificador = switch (resto) {
        case 0 -> "5";
        case 1 -> "0";
        default -> (11 - resto) + "";
    };

    String trnValido = trn.substring(0, 2) + trnAValidar+digitoVerificador + trn.substring(10).trim();
    System.out.println(trnValido);
    return trnValido;
```

como verás hay dos truquitos, el primero es usar los índices de un IntStream, y el otro es usar el nuevo switch.

Al evitar repetir el mismo valor muchas veces y poner en su lugar una variable  hacemos que el programa sea más fácil de modificar y por lo tanto de mantener